# create a file in c++ like when you press right-click->new->new text document

Tags: c++, c, file, createfile

What is the C/C++ command for creating a file in a certain directory with the name of a certain variable read from the keyboard ?
For example: a text file with the name John previously read from the keyboard, the program will create the file John.txt

Comment: So, to answer this question, it would help very much if you posted some code showing what you have tried so far - as the answer will very much depend on which part you are struggling with. [I take it you are not actually wishing to open john.txt as a file in notepad?]

Comment: I used this : std::ofstream outfile ("test.txt"); to create the file but the problem is that I need the name of the file to be a variable which changes when the user enters some new data. I don't know how to do this(to start this) and I also don't know how to open the new file created(in order to write on it) since the name is always a new  one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like this, in this example I ask for the filename using the keyboard, then I create the file using `fopen` and passing it to filename written by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   FILE *f;
   char filename[40], path[255];
   strcpy(path,"folder/path/"); //copies the folder path into the variable

   printf("Insert your filename\n");
   scanf("%s",&filename);

   strcpy(path,filename);
   f = fopen(path,'w'); //w is for writing permission   

   //Your operations
   fclose(f);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is another example using POO which is better for C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  string path = "my path";
  string filename;

  cout << "Insert your filename" << endl;
  cin >> filename;
  path = path + filename;

  ofstream f; 
  f.open (path.c_str()); //Here is your created file

  //Your operations
  f.close();
  return 0;
}
```

P.D: This example uses Unix's paths.

Comment: thank you this is what i've searched for

Comment: I'm glad it worked, select it as answer and upvote it :)

Comment: I've sign up yesterday so the only thing i can is to accept as answer (i need 15 reputation to upvote it:D)

Answer (score 0):

C way: `FILE* f = fopen(filename,"w");` (assuming that you want to write to it, else the second argument is "r".)

C++ way: `std::fstream f(filename,std::ios::out);` (assuming that you want to write, for reading it's std::ios::in)

Also, try to search C/C++ documentation before asking such questions. Check out [this](http://en.cppreference.com) site next time.

Comment: I used this : std::ofstream outfile ("test.txt"); to create the file but the problem is that I need the name of the file to be a variable which changes when the user enters some new data. I don't know how to do this(to start this) and I also don't know how to open the new file created(in order to write on it) since the name is always a new one

Comment: it's not about binary opening

Comment: Well, I'm so confused right now. Do you want to change the filename with each user input? And then rewrite all the old data, or append to the existing? Please, be more specific to make it more easy to help you.

Comment: What binary opening? Are you sure you know what are you talking about?

Comment: I received the answer above:D Thank you very much :)

Comment: I see. I'm glad that you resolved your problem. glhf